# Openlayers 3 readExtensions GPX

Tags: openlayers-3

I am new to javascript but am trying to read the heart rate extension from a GPX track with openlayers 3.

[Sample GPX track point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPKYq.jpg)

The drag and drop interaction accepts a constructor for the GPX format.  I can read the basic information (lat, lon, ele, time) by passing the ol.format.GPX constructor but I can't figure out how to pass a constructor with the 'readExtensions' option.

According to the openlayers documentation (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.format.GPX.html), it should be a callback function but when I run my code, I get an error: TypeError: d[g] is not a constructor.

```
    var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
  formatConstructors: [
    //ol.format.GPX(extFeature),
    new ol.format.GPX({
        readExtensions: function(x) {
          return x;
        }
        }),
    ol.format.GeoJSON,
    ol.format.IGC,
    ol.format.KML,
    ol.format.TopoJSON
  ]
});
```

How can I format the constructor so that I get the extensions back as well as the standard feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom format inheriting from `ol.format.GPX` and pass your constructor to the drag&drop interaction:

```
var CustomFormat = function() {
  ol.format.GPX.call(this, {
    // custom options
  });
};
ol.inherits(CustomFormat, ol.format.GPX);

var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
  formatConstructors: [
    CustomFormat,
    ...
  ]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zmprrj7/